# How do the roots of "$x^2 + bx + c$" change as $b$ is kept constant and $c$ is changed?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, quadratics

Consider the function $x^2 + bx + c$

How do the (real or complex) roots of the equation change if $b$ is held constant and $c$ is changed? I.e. Which patterns are evident?

**What would it look like if you plotted the locus of the roots on an Argand diagram as $c$ is changed?**

Also, how do the roots change if $c$ is held constant and $b$ is changed? Again, which patterns (if any) are evident?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think there's a bit more that could be said about the dynamic geometry that may not be immediately obvious to someone upon first looking at that formula; see my answer for what I have in mind.

Comment: Oh, ok. I guess I did not get the point.

Answer (score 1):

(**Note:** Everything below assumes that $b$ and $c$ are real numbers.)

First, I'll explain how you can get a good handle on the answer this question yourself by hand, and then link to some interactive visualizations. Finally, a bit more work can get a more exact picture.

#### Exploratory Algebra

The zeros of $x^2+bx+c$ (the roots of $x^{2}+bx+c=0$) are given by $x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^{2}-4c}}{2}$. If the [discriminant](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform2.htm) $b^{2}-4c>0$, then $\sqrt{b^{2}-4c}>0$ and the roots are real and distinct. If $b^{2}-4c=0$, then the roots coincide at $x=-\dfrac{b}{2}$. If $b^{2}-4c<0$, then $\sqrt{b^{2}-4c}=i\sqrt{4c-b^{2}}=i\sqrt{\left|b^{2}-4c\right|}$ and the roots are nonreal and distinct.

For convenience, set $r=-\dfrac{b}{2}$ and $s=\dfrac{\sqrt{\left|b^{2}-4c\right|}}{2}=\sqrt{\left|r^{2}-c\right|}$, and note that since $b$ is kept constant, so is $r$. Then $b^{2}-4c>0$ is equivalent to $c<r^{2}$, and the roots of $x^{2}+bx+c$ can be written as: $x=\begin{cases}r\pm s & \text{ if }c<r^{2}\\r & \text{ if }c=r^{2}\\r\pm is & \text{ if }c>r^{2}\end{cases}$.

Therefore, all the roots lie in a region shaped like $+$ centered at $r$ (the union of the real axis and the vertical line through $r$). Moreover, the distance $s$ from a zero to $r$ is precisely the square root of the absolute difference between $c$ and $r^{2}$, and it's horizontal if $c<r^{2}$ and vertical if $c>r^{2}$.

With calculus, one can derive that as $c$ increases at a constant rate, $s$ is changing at a speed of $\dfrac{1}{2s}$ times that rate (so the roots are moving arbitrarily fast near $r$).

---

#### Interactives

[Here is an interactive](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ujdzrhw87q) I just made in Desmos where you can watch the locations of the roots move as you vary $b$ and/or $c$. If you already have the Wolfram CDF player or have access to Mathematica, you can play with a similar interactive previously developed by Robert Baillie [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SlidingTheRootsOfQuadratics/).

---

#### More Algebra

Instead of an interactive/animation, we can get a clearer picture by figuring out exactly what the picture of the dependence of the roots on $c$ is. In other words, by preparing a 3D picture of the real and complex parts of the roots for each $c$. We can do this with a computer just from the work above, but we wouldn't be certain of the exact shape of the picture. An approach that will work is to create a pair of parametric functions on the axes $\text{real part of }x,\text{imaginary part of }x,c$. Since $x^2+bx+c=0$, $c=-x^2-bx$, so that $c$ can be written as a function of a root.

When the pair of roots is real, they're just $r\pm s$, so we can use something in place of $s$ as a parameter ($c$ can be written as a function of $s$). Then $\mathbf{f}(t)=\left(t+r,0,-(t+r)^2-b(t+r)\right)=\left(t+r,0,-(t+r)^2+2r(t+r)\right)$ is a parametric plot of the locations of the real roots, with $t=0$ corresponding to the double-root. Note that this is a parabola in our 3D space.

When the pair of roots is nonreal, they are $r\pm is$, so the real part is $r$ and $-x^2-bx=-(r\pm is)^2+2r(r\pm is)=r^{2}+s^{2}$. Then $\mathbf{g}(t)=\left(r,t,t^2+r^2\right)$ is a parametric plot of the locations of the complex roots, with $t=0$ corresponding to the double-root. Note that this is another parabola in our 3D space.

---

#### Static 3D picture

Plotting the $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{g}$ in the same space, we obtain a picture like this (here $r=1$):
[image: two parabolas]

The Mathematica code I used is

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{x + 1, 0, 2 (x + 1) - (x + 1)^2}, {1, x, 1 + x^2}}, {x, -2, 2}, 
BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Green, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick]] 
/. Line[pts_] :> Tube[pts, .05], 
Graphics3D[{Text["Real", {3.5, 0, 0}], Text["Imag", {0, 2.5, 0}], Text[C, {0, 0, 5.5}]}]]
```

Comment: One of the things that I dont understand is how you came to the value for s, i.e why does s = (square root of absolute value of b² - 4c)/2? (in the explanatory algebra section at the top). I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain. Thanks.

Comment: @Michelle Consider similar situations with numbers. $\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{|3|}$, since $3>0$. And $\sqrt{-2}=i\sqrt{2}=i\sqrt{|-2|}$ since $-2<0$. So any square root of a real number is related to the square root of its absolute value, possibly with a factor of $i$. Using this same idea, I figured that introducing $\sqrt{\left|b^2-4ac\right|}$ would help in understanding. To avoid having to write something like $s/2$ all the time, I defined $s$ to be $\frac12\sqrt{\left|b^2-4ac\right|}$. Incidentally, "exploratory algebra" was not a typo. There are many different choices you can make when exploring.

Comment: Ok, but why did you multiply (sqrt (abs value(b² - 4ac)) by 1/2? Sorry for all the questions, but I cant see where the 1/2 comes into the situation. I feel really unintelligent right now :(

Comment: @Michelle, sorry about any confusion; I'm happy to answer questions about my answers. If I had just defined $S=\sqrt{|b^2-4c|}$ and $R=-b$, then by the quadratic formula, the roots in the real case would be $(R\pm S)/2$ and the roots in the complex case would be $(R\pm iS)/2$. Only to avoid writing "$/2$" in so many places, and for no other reason, I made the choice to define $r=-b/2$ and $s=(\sqrt{|b^2-4c|})/2$ instead. The $1/2$ comes into the definition of $s$ because I chose it to simplify the algebra that followed.

Comment: @Michelle, "feeling unintelligent": Unfortunately, things like "exploring in mathematics by making convenience-driven choices" are not emphasized early on. And keep in mind that I'm not a math peer; I'm a math teacher. Also, since your question had [little context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/26369) (this is probably why the question is closed), I had to make a guess at what level to pitch my answer at. (Not to mention that [answers are not just for the question asker](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11424/26369).) If you just keep on asking questions, you'll keep learning.